# How can I change the App Bar titles in "Android Studio"?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am pretty new to Android Studio and that might even be a dumb question but I didn't find anything for it on the Internet and I am looking for more than 5 hours now...

The important thing to mention is that I am using the prebuilt "Navigation Drawer Activity" on Android Studio, to which I'm new.

[image: This is one title I want to change the name from...]

I don't even know which file is causing it to be called "home" I didn't find it, but if you know pls let me know so I will add the code of that file

app_bar_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I also want to change:

[image: these elements]

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `res/values/strings.xml`, you can by editing these values:

```
<string name="menu_home">Home</string>
<string name="menu_gallery">Gallery</string>
<string name="menu_slideshow">Slideshow</string>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can change it in your strings.xml file 
res/values/strings.xml